# Limit of the ratio of two non-Riemann sums.

Tags: integration, riemann-sum, partitions-for-integration

Let $\left[ {a,b} \right] \subset \mathbb{R}$  and $f,g:\left[ {a,b} \right] \to \mathbb{R}$  be two Riemann-integrable functions.

Let $a = {x_0} < {x_1} < {x_2}... < {x_n} = b$  be a partition of $\left[ {a,b} \right]$  and let $\Delta x = \mathop {\max }\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 1} \left( {{x_{i + 1}} - {x_i}} \right)$.

Let ${t_i} \in \left[ {{x_i},{x_{i + 1}}} \right],\;i = 0,n - 1$  and let  $k \in {\mathbb{N}^*}$.

I’d like to prove that

$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 1} {{{\left( {{x_{i + 1}} - {x_i}} \right)}^k}f\left( {{t_i}} \right)} }}{{\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 1} {{{\left( {{x_{i + 1}} - {x_i}} \right)}^k}g\left( {{t_i}} \right)} }} = \frac{{\int\limits_a^b {f\left( x \right){\text{d}}x} }}{{\int\limits_a^b {g\left( x \right){\text{d}}x} }}$

It is obvious for equally spaced partitions  ${x_{i + 1}} - {x_i} \equiv \Delta x$

$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 1} {\Delta {x^k}f\left( {{t_i}} \right)} }}{{\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 1} {\Delta {x^k}g\left( {{t_i}} \right)} }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 1} {\Delta xf\left( {{t_i}} \right)} }}{{\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 1} {\Delta xg\left( {{t_i}} \right)} }} = \frac{{\int\limits_a^b {f\left( x \right){\text{d}}x} }}{{\int\limits_a^b {g\left( x \right){\text{d}}x} }}$

But I don’t see how to do it in the general case?

Comment: Some context would be advisable. Which is your source ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo My question is motivated by my unpublished works on point null hypothesis testing problems such as the Behrens-Fisher problem or the Jeffreys-Lindley paradox. Please see my draft paper [A Fully Bayesian Solution to k-Sample Tests for Comparison and the Behrens-Fisher Problem Based on the Henstock-Kurzweil Integral](http://vixra.org/abs/1909.0376). Problems with discrete parameters are OK. But problems with continuous ones are degenerate. Therefore, I approximate continuous problems by sequences of discrete ones and then I take the limit solution...

Comment: @TonyPiccolo This limit is trivial for discrete random variables defined on equipartitions but I still need to prove that it remains the same for arbitrary partitions. Hence my little problem.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Anyway, the main "theorem" of my paper is not satisfactory and I need to fix this. But the main idea should be OK.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Thanks to you, I learned that it is sufficient to consider equipartitions (but arbitrary tagged points) for the Riemann integral. I need to think about it..............

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Happy new year Tony. Any thought about this problem please?

Comment: What goes wrong here is that for $k >1$ we have $$\left|\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(t_i)(x_{i+1}- x_i)^k\right|\leqslant \underset{0 \leqslant i \leqslant n-1}\max(x_{i+1}-x_i)^{k-1}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |f(t_i)|(x_{i+1}- x_i) \to 0 \cdot \int_a^b |f(x)| \, dx = 0$$ as $n \to \infty$ and $\Delta x \to 0$ and similarly for $g$.  Effectively there is a $0/0$ indeterminancy in the limit of the ratio so convergence to the ratio of the integrals may not hold depending upon the choice of non-uniform partition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This result can fail to hold with non-uniform partitions. For a counterexample, we look for Riemann integrable functions $f$ and $g$ and  a sequence of partitions

$$P_n: a = x_0^{(n)}<x_1^{(n)} < \ldots < x_{n-1}^{(n)} < x_n^{(n)} = b$$

along with a choice of tags $t_j^{n} \in [x_{j},x_{j+1}]$ where

$$\tag{*}\Delta x := \|P_n\| = \underset{0 \leqslant j \leqslant n-1} \max \left(x_{j+1}^{(n)}-x_j^{(n)}\right) \underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow 0$$ and, such that for some $k > 1$,

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0, \,n \to \infty}\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f(t_j^{(n)})(x_{j+1}^{(n)}- x_j^{(n)})^k}{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} g(t_j^{(n)})(x_{j+1}^{(n)}- x_j^{(n)})^k} \neq \frac{\int_a^bf(x) \, dx}{\int_a^b g(x) \, dx}$$

**Note that condition (*) is an essential requirement here as it ensures convergence of Riemann sums (with $k=1$) to the respective integrals.**

Take $[a,b] = [1,e]$, $f(x) = 1$, $g(x) = x$, $k = 2$, partition points $x_j^{(n)} = e^{j/n}$ and tags $t_j^{(n)} = e^{j/n}$ for $j=0,1,\ldots,n$.

In this case, the $n$th partition is $P_n : 1 < e^{1/n} < e^{2/n} < \ldots <  e^{(n-1)/n}< e$, and we have

$$\Delta x = \|P_n\| = \max_{0 \leqslant j  \leqslant n-1}(e^{(j+1)/n}-e^{j/n}) = \max_{0 \leqslant j  \leqslant n-1}e^{j/n}(e^{1/n}-1) = e^{(n-1)/n}(e^{1/n}-1), $$

where $\Delta x = e^{(n-1)/n}(e^{1/n}-1)\to e\cdot 0 = 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Note that, with $k=1$,

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f(t_j^{(n)})(x_{j+1}^{(n)}- x_j^{(n)})= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} 1 \cdot (e^{(j+1)/n}- e^{j/n)})= (e^{1/n} - 1)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}e^{j/n} =  (e^{1/n} - 1)\frac{e-1}{e^{1/n} -1}\\ \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} g(t_j^{(n)})(x_{j+1}^{(n)}- x_j^{(n)})= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} e^{j/n} \cdot (e^{(j+1)/n}- e^{j/n)})= (e^{1/n} - 1)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}e^{(2j)/n} =  (e^{1/n} - 1)\frac{e^2-1}{e^{2/n} -1} ,$$

and, as we expect for Riemann sums,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f(t_j^{(n)})(x_{j+1}^{(n)}- x_j^{(n)})= e-1 = \int_1^e f(x) \, dx\\ \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f(t_j^{(n)})(x_{j+1}^{(n)}- x_j^{(n)})= \frac{e^2-1}{2} = \int_1^e g(x) \, dx$$

However, for $k=2$,

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f(t_j^{(n)})(x_{j+1}^{(n)}- x_j^{(n)})^k= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} 1 \cdot (e^{(j+1)/n}- e^{j/n)})^2= (e^{1/n} - 1)^2\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}e^{(2j)/n} =  (e^{1/n} - 1)^2\frac{e^2-1}{e^{2/n} -1}\\ \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} g(t_j^{(n)})(x_{j+1}^{(n)}- x_j^{(n)})^k= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} e^{j/n} \cdot (e^{(j+1)/n}- e^{j/n)})^2= (e^{1/n} - 1)^2\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}e^{(3j)/n} =  (e^{1/n} - 1)^2\frac{e^3-1}{e^{3/n} -1} ,$$

and,

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0, \,n \to \infty}\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f(t_j^{(n)})(x_{j+1}^{(n)}- x_j^{(n)})^k}{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} g(t_j^{(n)})(x_{j+1}^{(n)}- x_j^{(n))})^k} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{e^2-1}{e^3-1}\frac{e^{3/n}-1}{e^{2/n}-1} = \frac{3}{2}\frac{e^2-1}{e^3-1} \\\neq \frac{2}{e+1}  = \frac{e-1}{\frac{e^2-1}{2}}= \frac{\int_a^bf(x) \, dx}{\int_a^b g(x) \, dx}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot RRL. As stated in the comments above, this simple question arises from my  research about the Behrens-Fisher problem, which comes in two different variants, discrete and continuous. The situation is as follows: 1) the standard Bayesian solutions in both cases are not correct and satisfactory in many respects 2) the continuous problem has a trivial and totally useless absolute solution because we directly jump into the uncountable 3) the discrete problem has straightforward absolute and relative solutions. Hence it remains to find the relative solution to the continuous problem...

Comment: ... by 1) approximating the continuous problem by a sequence of discrete one. This is done by partitioning the parameter space 2) computing the relative solutions to those problem 3) taking the limit of those solutions. But as you shown, this limit solution does not exist. Hence, we conclude that the continuous problem is actually mathematically ill-posed unless we can argue, justify that we should restrict ourselves to particular sequences of partitions, e.g. equipartitions. Therefore, I'm looking for some intuitive principle, typically an invariance principle...

Comment: ... that would imply the restriction to e.g. equipartitions. Any idea please?

Comment: @FabricePautot: You're welcome.  I'll have to delve more deeply into your work and see where passing to a continuous formulation breaks down.

Comment: Thanks. That would be great!!! The beginning of my paper is correct (criticism of the classical solution + solutions to the discrete problem). Only the very end is not (limit relative solution of the continuous problem), I was way too fast because I was not expecting the continuous problem to be ill-posed at all since it is supposed to be well-posed ... according to the standard, but wrong, solution.

Comment: @FabricePautot: Many thanks for the bounty.  I'm having a difficult time working through your very technical paper as I am quite rusty in this area.  Perhaps another question that focuses more on where the statistical derivation breaks down will attract more help.

Comment: +1 there for the excellent answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this reduces to two copies of a problem which has never been successfully solved in the history of mathematics. The best you could do is conjecture, but you should be able to at least show that your conjecture is reasonable.

As a matter of fact, you can't even prove the result which you claimed was obvious. It's obvious because we accept this definition of the integral. That does not mean that it can be proven unfortunately...

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get your point. The situation is as follows. We have a problem that comes in two different variants, discrete and continuous. The standard solutions to both problems are not correct for many reasons. The solution to the discrete problem is straightforward. Hence, it remains to solve the continuous one by i) approximating the continuous problem by a sequence of discrete ones ii) solve those discrete problems iii) prove there exists a unique limit solution. But, as shown by Alex above, that is not the case. Hence we conclude that the problem is actually ill-posed unless...

Comment: ... we add some well-chosen constraints or conditions that make it well-posed, e.g. restrict ourself to equipartitions. That's the next step...

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph: for equipartitions, the limit is the ratio of both integrals, isn't it?

Comment: @FabricePautot here's what I mean: If we are taking the limit of a rational function, say f(x)/g(x), then we can rewrite the single limit as the ratio of the two limits. The limit of ratio of the two equipartitioned Riemann sums results in the ratio of the two integrals only because we it literally is just a certain definition of one integral divided by the definition of another integral. There is no way to "prove" this definition is equivalent to other definitions we may use such as the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus...

Comment: @FabricePautot I also want to point out there are some issue with taking the limit dx->0 specifically because this means the length of the intervals will have to decrease as different rates. How might we account for this? One way I want to suggest is by using a procedure that doubles the amount of intervals every step by including the midpoint of the interval. I'm unsure if this will get you where you want to go, but that's my thoughts. Hope this helps.